# unable to run RunProgramInGuest using vmrun in VmwareWorkstation 15

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vmware-workstation

While running the command

`/usr/bin/vmrun -T ws -gu username -gp password runProgramInGuest /home/vmware/Ubuntu\ 64-bit/Ubuntu\ 64-bit.vmx -noWait -activeWindow -interactive /usr/bin/strace -o /home/logdir/trace.txt -etrace=forkcloneexecvechdiropencreatclosesocketconnectacceptbindreadwriteunlinkrenamekillpipedupdup2 -s 216 -f /home/malware_analysis/bb0b00438aa782f41a02b434f2c525f2d4a4662604e4254dca8c6a896adaff3a`

I am getting the following error:

`Error: The specified guest user must be logged in interactively to perform this operation`

My setup is as follows :

1. VMware Workstation 15
2. Host OS -Ubuntu 16.04
3. Guest OS OS -Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .lck files created in the vmware folder where virtual machine files are stored.